# Java: Manipulate docx document saved in Clob/Blob as text

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, apache-tika

I have a word document saved in Oracle Clob or mysql Blob I wrote the following code to read from DB --> save into .docx --> manipulate text inside docx document. my question is there any way to manipulate the text inside docx document without writing the data on docx document?
Thanks :)

```
private static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";
private static String username = "root";
private static String password = "root";




public static void main( String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, IOException
{
     Connection conn = null;

      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

      String sql = "SELECT name, description, data FROM documents ";
      PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
      ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery();
      while (resultSet.next()) {
          String name = resultSet.getString(1);
          System.out.println("Name        = " + name);
          String description = resultSet.getString(2);
          System.out.println("Description = " + description);

          //
          // Get the character stream of our CLOB data
          //
          Blob blob = resultSet.getBlob(3);
         // System.out.println(convertLOB(blob));//convertLOB(blob).toString());
          OutputStream fwriter = new FileOutputStream("C:\\The Appfuce Primer.docx");
         readFromBlob(blob,fwriter);

    String target = "C:\\The Appfuce Primer.docx";

    File document = new File(target);
    Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();

    ContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();

    try {
      parser.parse(new FileInputStream(document), handler, metadata, new ParseContext());


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TikaException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(metadata);
    System.out.println(handler.toString());
      }
}
      final static int bBufLen = 4 * 8192;
      public static long readFromBlob(Blob blob, OutputStream out)
               throws SQLException, IOException {
                 InputStream in = blob.getBinaryStream();
                 int length = -1;
                 long read = 0;
                 byte[] buf = new byte[bBufLen];
                 while ((length = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
                     out.write(buf, 0, length);
                     read += length;
                 }
                 in.close();
                 return read;
             }
```

Comment: What kind of manipulation are you planning to do?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by manipulating "the text inside docx document without writing the data on docx document"?

Comment: well this word document has a template like the following

*** EVENT(S) DESCRIPTION (INCLUDE SYMPTOMS LEADING TO EVENT(S) AND FINAL DIAGNOSIS)***: I have problems with this blood sugar monitoring tool because the needle is painful to use.

I want to read the text only after the starts and send it to a service

Comment: Pls describe the issue in a way that somebody, who is not familiar with your application (meaning entire SO) can understand it!

Comment: the whole idea is there is a word document saved in DB i want to get this document read the text inside it and send this text  to a service

Comment: Have you tried out any java components that are able to parse docx documents if they can extract text? According to for example docx4java's cheat sheet, it can extract the document's content as text. http://www.docx4java.org/docx4j/plutext-docx4j_on_a_page-v300.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Apache POI project to get access to the content of your .docx document.

https://poi.apache.org/document/quick-guide-xwpf.html

Comment: Thanks, i have tried this and it works i was using Apache tika.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can call parser.parse directly using **blob.getBinaryStream()**:

```
...
parser.parse(blob.getBinaryStream(), handler, metadata, new ParseContext());
...
```

So you don't have to create a temporary file containing the docx document.

Comment: And how do you propose this solution to parse a docx document?

Comment: I thought he already uses AutoDetectParser from Apache Tika to extract data from docx documents and  just doesn't want to write the document's content temporarily into a file.

Comment: @MartinM. you are right I'm using Apache tika and you gave me what I need, Thanks!